# How to create Dynamic, not predefined, CSS styles in Vue (like we can in Angular)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuex

In Angular we can dynamically set css properties, like this:

```
<style ng-if="color">
.theme-color { color: {{color}}; }
.theme-background-color { background-color: {{color}}; }
.theme-border-color { border-color: {{color}}; }
</style>
```

In Vue, we can modify :class=... but that limits us to predefined class options,   and :style... that doesn't allow us to use class names.

Is there a way to achieve dynamic CSS as above? Or do we have to code the styles so that they include all color properties?

Thanks

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? You may be able to approach it with CSS variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this has some sort of user colour picking intervention; I would store the user's chosen colour in the state, so it's globally accessible.

Then within your component, you could do the following...

```
<app :style="themeStyles"></app>

export default {
  computed: {
    themeStyles () {
      return {
        color: store.state.themeColor,
        backgroundColor: store.state.themeColor,
        borderColor: store.state.themeColor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Pseudocode so to provide example quickly)

Obviously, use it on whatever component you need - but it should do the trick, so long as you have a way of storing user's input for the themeColor itself & store it in the state.

**Edit: additional option**

[JSS](http://cssinjs.org/setup?v=v9.8.0)

Comment: This wouldn't work as smoothly as it seems it would.This is relying totally on the cascade. As soon as a color is set on a child that's the new color there downward.

Comment: @BillCriswell do you mean it won't win specificity wars? If so, you _could_ add an !important..

I see you're point though, will have another think.
You could possibly generate classes and assign their rules in computed, much in the same way listed above but with a different syntax/structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need Internet Explorer support you can use CSS variables.

Here's a quick CodeSandbox with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rr80o6kq3n

Here's the relevant code.

```
<template>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.foo {
  --theme-color: black;
}

.bar {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: color 0.2s;
  color: var(--theme-color);
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      hue: 0,
    }
  },

  watch: {
    hue (hue) {
      this.$el.style.setProperty(
        "--theme-color",
        `hsl(${hue % 360}, 100%, 50%)`,
      )
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    window.setInterval(() => {
      this.hue += 20
    }, 500)
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: MSFT was my biggest customer for over twenty years.  And I'm perfectly happy to ignore them - and NOT support the msft stack. ;)  That said, I prefer to work within the Vue metaphor.  But thank you for the good suggestion.  :)

Comment: It just wouldn't work in IE <= 11. It would work fine in Edge.